# Hyper-V iterate over network adapters C# Powershell Get-VM

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I am currently trying to iterate over a List of Network adapters from a PSObject. I currently get all VMs from my Hyper-V instance:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-VM");
foreach(PSObject obj in ps.Invoke()){
   // problem is below on the cast
   var ps = (PSObject) obj.Properties["NetworkAdapters"].Value;
}
```

I cannot cast the Network adapters successfully to an object. Looking at the object at runtime the object type is `System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMNetworkAdapter>` but this is not accessible; I just want to cast it to the correct object to iterate over and populate my model.

Comment: Does `obj.Properties.NetworkAdapters` not work?

Comment: obj.Properties.NetworkAdapter will Cast to PSPropertyInfo, but i need to iterate over the values. E.g get all the details about the Adapters.

Comment: Which value? There are several values on the network adapters.

Comment: The main property i am interested in is IPAddresses which is an array of string, but i need to be able to iterate over each NetworkAdapter.

Comment: Can you not pipe to get-VMNetworkAdapter command?

Comment: I gave up trying to access the NetworkAdapters object, and query directly using Get-VMNetworkAdapter separately.